# Tomcat 7 High CPU Usage on Boot with No Connections

Tags: java, tomcat, cpu, netty, hornetq

We are running Tomcat 7.0.34 on CentOS 6.3 (fully patched), and all of our appservers' CPUs spike up as soon as the server boots.  There are NO connections being made to Tomcat.  It appears there are a couple of CPU cores being completely consumed by something that is running inside our webapp.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what could be causing this issue.  Has anyone seen this before?

I should mention this only happens on the CentOS boxes.  My Windows tomcat server does not exhibit this behavior running the same application.

***Relevant Technologies***

We are using Tomcat's session replication, Replicated EHCache and HornetQ for JMS.

***Java Versions Tested***

JDK 1.7.0 Update 10 and JDK 1.6.0 Update 38

***Kill -3 Runnable Threads***

```
    "http-apr-8080-Acceptor-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598183000 nid=0x46b9 runnable [0x00007f2500685000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.accept(Native Method)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Acceptor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1013)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    "http-apr-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598181800 nid=0x46b8 runnable [0x00007f2500786000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.accept(Native Method)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Acceptor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1013)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    "New I/O boss #26" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253d4fb000 nid=0x462f runnable [0x00007f250c49c000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
            - locked <0x00000006ab002568> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
            - locked <0x00000006ab002558> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
            - locked <0x00000006ab0024d0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:64)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:409)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:206)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:41)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    "New I/O worker #25" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253d4e4000 nid=0x462e runnable [0x00007f250c59d000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
            - locked <0x00000006aefbcab8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
            - locked <0x00000006aefbcaa8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
            - locked <0x00000006aefbca60> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:64)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:409)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:206)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    "New I/O worker #24" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253d4b9000 nid=0x462d runnable [0x00007f250c69e000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
            - locked <0x00000006ab002c70> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
            - locked <0x00000006ab002c60> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
            - locked <0x00000006ab002bd8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:64)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:409)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:206)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

... ABOUT 20 MORE NIO WORKERS IN RUNNABLE STATE...

"New I/O worker #2" prio=10 tid=0x00007f253d054000 nid=0x4616 runnable [0x00007f250ddb5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x00000006adaa7070> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006adaa7060> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006adaa6fd8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:409)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:206)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"New I/O worker #1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f253d053000 nid=0x4615 runnable [0x00007f250deb6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x00000006adaa7bc0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006adaa7bb0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006adaa7b28> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:409)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:206)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"NamingBootstrap Pool(1)-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253c4f8800 nid=0x45fc runnable [0x00007f25842a3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at org.jnp.server.Main$AcceptHandler.run(Main.java:481)
        at org.jboss.util.threadpool.RunnableTaskWrapper.run(RunnableTaskWrapper.java:148)
        at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"RMI TCP Accept-1098" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253c4f4800 nid=0x45fb runnable [0x00007f25843a4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253cc2d800 nid=0x45e6 runnable [0x00007f25859b9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"RMI TCP Accept-40001" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253cc16000 nid=0x45da runnable [0x00007f25865c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Multicast Heartbeat Receiver Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f253cc18000 nid=0x45d8 runnable [0x00007f25867c7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
        - locked <0x00000006ab145b28> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
        - locked <0x00000006ab145b28> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
        - locked <0x000000067ffd9240> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
        - locked <0x00000006ab1459f0> (a java.net.MulticastSocket)
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver$MulticastReceiverThread.run(MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver.java:124)

"Tribes-MembershipReceiver" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f259895c800 nid=0x45d0 runnable [0x00007f258733a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
        - locked <0x00000006b8163208> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
        - locked <0x00000006b8163208> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
        - locked <0x00000006b8158768> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
        - locked <0x00000006b7b4fc30> (a java.net.MulticastSocket)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.receive(McastServiceImpl.java:340)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl$ReceiverThread.run(McastServiceImpl.java:534)

"NioReceiver" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f259892f000 nid=0x45cf runnable [0x00007f258743b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x00000006b8155008> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006b8155020> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006b78650a8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver.listen(NioReceiver.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver.run(NioReceiver.java:420)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"NioReceiver" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f259892f000 nid=0x45cf runnable [0x00007f258743b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x00000006b8155008> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006b8155020> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006b78650a8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver.listen(NioReceiver.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver.run(NioReceiver.java:420)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f25982e0800 nid=0x45cc runnable [0x00007f258c7a6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"RMI TCP Accept-9004" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f25982cb000 nid=0x45cb runnable [0x00007f258c8a7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f25982a7000 nid=0x45ca runnable [0x00007f258c9a8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:387)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:359)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f259817a800 nid=0x45c9 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598178000 nid=0x45c8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598175800 nid=0x45c7 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598173800 nid=0x45c6 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598171800 nid=0x45c5 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f259811c000 nid=0x45c2 runnable

"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598012000 nid=0x45bd runnable

"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598014000 nid=0x45be runnable

"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598015800 nid=0x45bf runnable

"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f2598017800 nid=0x45c0 runnable

"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f25980a6800 nid=0x45c1 runnable
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f25982e3000 nid=0x45cd waiting on condition
```

All of this seems VERY busy for a server that has just started up, has no replication peers, and has not yet accepted any requests.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like the JVM is doing network-related things.  I'd try the following to see if they reveal any clues:

- Use a packet monitor to see if there is incoming / outgoing network traffic on your ethernet or loopback.
- Use strace to see what syscalls the JVM is making
- Check the Tomcat log files.  And as an experiment change the logging configs so that you can see all DEBUG logging.
- Check the system logs including the security logs (if you have SELinux enabled.)

You could also try tweaking the tomcat configs to not use APR and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: All these threads are idle (blocked). I don't see any reason for the spike...

Maybe there's something on the native side... ... I would also check the Apr settings.

I don't see anything on HornetQ going on BTW

Comment: Thanks Stephen, using some of your suggestions plus the addition of jvisualvm, I have been able to narrow the issue down to Netty/HornetQ.  It seems HornetQ is eating up CPU and at least I know where to look now.

Comment: @Clebert Using jvisualvm, I was able to see there are 2 NIO worker threads that are eating up the CPU cores.  They trace back to Netty/HornetQ.  So I decided to drop the number of consumers I had down to a handful, and the CPU usage dropped right along with it.  The thing is, these consumers are not actually doing anything but checking the empty queues.  Do you have any suggestions how I might go about troubleshooting this further?

Comment: Since I have been able to track the issue down to the HornetQ consumers, I will close this one out and start a new question regarding the HornetQ issue I am having.  Thanks again for your help.